# R aggregate data on a daily basis if start and end times are available

Tags: r, time, time-series, aggregate, transformation

I have the following problem. I have a dataframe of the following strucutre:

```
        startdatetime         enddatetime  type amount
1 2019-02-01 03:35:00 2019-02-03 06:35:00 prod1  1e+03
2 2019-02-03 06:35:00 2019-02-05 09:35:00 prod1  5e+03
3 2019-02-05 09:35:00 2019-02-06 01:35:00 prod2  3e+07
4 2019-02-06 01:35:00 2019-02-06 03:35:00 prod1  1e+02
```

representing an amount produced in a certain time span (startdatetime and enddatetime). Now I want to aggregate these data on a daily basis. Lets ignore the incomplete day 2019-02-01 and start with 2019-02-02. First prod 1 was produced between 2019-02-01 03:35:00 and 2019-02-03 06:35:00 in total 1000 kg were produced. So for example, on 2019-02-02: `24/51*1000` = 470.58 of prod 1 were produced because `24h + 21h + 6h = 51h`.
The solution I have so far is based on a for and a while loop, but I guess there is a faster solution based on the package "lubridate" or else which I did not find. 
Any suggestion?
Below my code

```
#create test data set
mydata <- data.frame(startdatetime=c(as.POSIXct("2019-02-01 03:35:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-02-03 06:35:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-02-05 09:35:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-02-06 01:35:00")),
                     enddatetime  =c(as.POSIXct("2019-02-03 06:35:00"), as.POSIXct("2019-02-05 09:35:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-02-06 01:35:00"),as.POSIXct("2019-02-06 03:35:00")),
                     type=c("prod1","prod1","prod2","prod1"),
                     amount=c(1000,5000,30000000,100)) 

# take only full days into account and ignore the first and the last day
minstartday = min(mydata$startdatetime)+24*60*60
maxendday   = max(mydata$enddatetime)-24*60*60

#create a day index
timesindex <- seq(from = as.Date(format(minstartday, format = "%Y/%m/%d")), 
                  to   = as.Date(format(maxendday, format = "%Y/%m/%d")), by = "day")

# create an empty dataframe which will be filled with the production data for each day
prodperday <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(timesindex),
                         prod1=replicate(length(timesindex),0), 
                         prod2=replicate(length(timesindex),0), 
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

# loop over all entries and separate them into produced fractions per day
for (irow in 1:dim(mydata)[1]){
  timestart = mydata[irow,"startdatetime"]
  datestart = as.Date(format(timestart, format = "%Y/%m/%d"))
  timeend = timestart
  tota_run_time_in_h = (as.numeric((mydata[irow,"enddatetime"]-mydata[irow,"startdatetime"])))*24.
  while (timeend < mydata[irow,"enddatetime"]){
    timeend = min (as.POSIXct(datestart, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")+23*60*60-1,
                   mydata[irow,"enddatetime"])
    tdiff = as.numeric(timeend-timestart)
    fraction_prod = (tdiff/tota_run_time_in_h)*mydata[irow,"amount"]
    if (datestart %in% prodperday$Date){
      prodperday[prodperday$Date == datestart,as.character(mydata[irow,"type"])] = 
        prodperday[prodperday$Date == datestart,as.character(mydata[irow,"type"])] + fraction_prod
    }

    timestart = timeend+1
    datestart = as.Date(format(timestart, format = "%Y/%m/%d"))
    timeend = timestart
  }
}
```

and the result:

```
        Date     prod1   prod2
1 2019-02-02  470.5828       0
2 2019-02-03 1836.5741       0
3 2019-02-04 2352.9139       0
4 2019-02-05  939.5425 1126280
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

You know that the start date uses `24-starttime` production hours. The end date uses `endtime`hours, and all days inbetween obviously use 24 hours. So it is easy to calculate.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

pmap_dfr(mydata, ~ {
  hours       <- abs(as.numeric(difftime(..1, ..2, units = "hours")))
  day_seq     <- seq(as_date(..1), as_date(..2), by = "days")
  hours_start <- hour(..1) + minute(..1) / 60
  hours_end   <- hour(..2) + minute(..2) / 60

  production  <- c(
    ..4 * (24 - hours_start) / hours,
    rep(..4 * 24 / hours, max(length(day_seq) - 2, 0)),
    ..4 * hours_end / hours
  )
  tibble(
    day = day_seq,
    amount = production,
    type = ..3
  )
}) %>%
  group_by(day, type) %>%
  summarise(amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  spread(type, amount) %>%
  replace_na(list(prod1 = 0, prod2 = 0))


# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   day [6]
  day        prod1     prod2
  <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2019-02-01  400.        0 
2 2019-02-02  471.        0 
3 2019-02-03 1837.        0 
4 2019-02-04 2353.        0 
5 2019-02-05  940. 27031250 
6 2019-02-06 1300.  2968750.
```

The very first and last entries can then be deleted in the end if you want to do that.

Comment: Thx, I tried it on a subset of data (500 rows). This version took 58 seconds the one I posted in the question took 28 seconds, so about twice as fast. If one wants to apply it he/she needs to make sure that startdatetime and endtdatetime are defined as character and are in the right format. Otherwise the solution throws an error: ´as.posixlt.character(x tz ...) character string is not in a standard unambiguous format´

Answer (score 1):

The solution I propopose is not perfect because there are problems with boundaries but the idea to transform your data in production by hour and after aggregated them by day is probably a good idea.

I use as whished the two libraries :

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
```

The time of reference :

```
ref.times <- seq(from = min(mydata$startdatetime),
           to = max(mydata$enddatetime),
           by = "hour")
```

Construction of a database with production by hour :

```
newdata <- data.frame(hour = floor_date(ref.times, unit = "hour"),
                      prod1 = 0,
                      prod2 = 0,
                      day = floor_date(newdata$hour, unit= "day"))
for(i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
  ref.times <- seq(from = mydata$startdatetime[i],
                   to = mydata$enddatetime[i],
                   by = "hour")
  n <- length(floor_date(ref.times, "hour"))
  if(mydata[i, 3] == "prod1"){
    newdata[newdata$hour %in%  floor_date(ref.times, unit = "hour"), 2] <-
      rep(mydata[i, 4] / n, n)
  }else{
    newdata[newdata$hour %in%  floor_date(ref.times, unit = "hour"), 3] <-
      rep(mydata[i, 4] / n, n)
  }
}
```

Aggregation by day :

```
newdata %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise(prod1 = sum(prod1),
                                        prod2 = sum(prod2))
```

Comment: Thx: In the newdata declaration it must be ref.times instead of newdata$hour. I tested the solution and it took more than twice as long as my solution and more than 5 times as long as the solution by @erocoar